# Monaco Editor: Custom Undo / Redo

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm wondering how can we disable the default undo/redo stack and implement our own so that whenever the user press Ctrl-Z, customUndo() function is called.

I'm building a real-time code collaborator and reimplementing undo/redo action is needed.

I have been looking up the [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/index.html) and the [issues page](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues) on Github but didn't find much relevant information.

Please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editor.addCommand(monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.KEY_Z, function() {
   customUndo();
});
```